# SpriteKit - How to add the nodes so that they cover the whole screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I'm completely new in SpriteKit. I have to create a view similar to this image;

[image]

I'm using following code (courtesy of:[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780165/sprite-kit-add-random-sprite-nodes-to-the-scene-with-switch-case)) to draw the leaves;

```
-(void)createObjects {

// Create random start point
float randomYPoint = arc4random_uniform(self.view.bounds.size.height);
float randomXPoint = arc4random_uniform(self.view.bounds.size.width);
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(randomXPoint, randomYPoint);

// Create random object and add to scene
SKTexture* objectTexture;
switch (arc4random_uniform(8)) {
    case 0:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafOne"];
        break;
    case 1:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafTwo"];
        break;
    case 2:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafThree"];
        break;
    case 3:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafFour"];
        break;
    case 4:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafFive"];
        break;
    case 5:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafSix"];
        break;
    case 6:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafSeven"];
        break;
    case 7:
        objectTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"leafEight"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
SKSpriteNode *object = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:objectTexture];

object.position = startPoint;
object.name = @"object";

[self addChild: object];
}
```

Currently I repeatedly call this method (around 300 times in loop) to fill the whole screen with leaves which is a bad approach.

1) How do I know that the whole view is filled with leaves so that I stop the loop?

2) This approach is heavy on CPU and memory, how can I make it efficient and less CPU hungry?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Strangely enough when I did a Google search "spritekit placing random images" results do come up. As for the second part, not gonna happen.

Comment: My question wasn't solely about creating a node with random images. I meant how to add the random nodes in the view until the full screen is covered up? whats the stopping condition? etc. Thanks for the comment anyways.

Comment: You are going to get a much better response by showing what code you have tried so far. Saying you want something done but have no clue how to do it, is not gonna get you anywhere. Especially if the issues are not simple ones. Also, your 2 questions are totally unrelated and should be 2 separate postings.

Comment: @sangony could you please check it now?

Comment: Now you're cooking with gas :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to another question but it also applies here...

This is not an off the shelf kind of function in SK. Your only solution would be to create a hack to do what you want. One possible approach might be to create a very small node and place it in various positions on the screen, using a loop. For example (x,y position), 0,0 -> 4,0 -> 8,0 and so on...

You can use the `-(BOOL)intersectsNode:(SKNode *)node` to see if this node intersects any other node.

Another approach might be to use the same kind of logic but use `-(BOOL)containsPoint:(CGPoint)p` instead.

Both approaches would be processor intensive so you should only run them sparingly.